# Get data from json but only for one record

Tags: angularjs, json

I've this JSON:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "return": {
    "totalItem": 7,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "pageSize": 7,
    "items": {
      "phones": [
        "(48) 9999-9999"
      ],
      "users": {
        "manager": {
          "id_user": "5819",
          "name": "Síndico Ilhas Belas",
          "user": "sindico.teste@domain.com",
          "photo": "https://domain.amazonaws.com/files/upload/2015/07/25/5819.55b32d90e69ab3.05638898_873f970f8d259.jpg"
        },
        "employees": [
          {
            "id_user": "2",
            "name": "José Perez",
            "user": "pepe@domain.com",
            "photo": "https://.amazonaws.com/files/upload/2013/10/07/2.52523a0451c3c5.59697102_7a4188d3.jpg",
            "groups": [
              {
                "id_group": "33",
                "name": "Portaria"
              }
            ],
            "work_details": {
              "work_schedule": "8-12hs e 14-18hs",
              "work_activities": "Supervisionar os trabalhos de conservação"
            }
          },
          {
            "id_user": "15142",
            "name": "Marcos Rojas",
            "user": "rojas@c.com",
            "photo": "http://www.domain.com/themes/intra/img/sf_ele.gif",
            "groups": [
              {
                "id_group": "589",
                "name": "Zeladoria"
              }
            ],
            "work_details": {
              "work_schedule": "8h 12h",
              "work_activities": "Zeladoria"
            }
          },
          {
            "id_user": "18833",
            "name": "Portaria",
            "user": "teste@domain.com",
            "photo": "http://www.domain.com/themes/intra/img/sf_ele.gif",
            "groups": [
              {
                "id_group": "33",
                "name": "Portaria"
              }
            ],
            "work_details": {
              "work_schedule": "8hs por dia. 8-12hs e 14-18hs",
              "work_activities": "Supervisionar os trabalhos de conservação"
            }
          }
        ],
        "boardMembers": [
          {
            "id_user": "8189",
            "name": "Ana Maria",
            "user": "8189",
            "photo": "http://www.domain.com/themes/intra/img/sf_ela.gif",
            "groups": [
              {
                "id_group": "722",
                "name": "Subsíndico"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id_user": "11442",
            "name": "Luciana Zath",
            "user": "lzath@mail.com",
            "photo": "http://www.domain.com/themes/intra/img/sf_ela.gif",
            "groups": [
              {
                "id_group": "1456",
                "name": "Conselho fiscal"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because `manager` is only one record, i can't get it with `ng-repeat` in this code

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="(manager, name) in items">
    <pre>{{name}}</pre>
</div>
```

JSON returns all data, but i need return only `manager` data, for example:

Name, User (email) and photo

And controller:

```
// Controller of about.
appControllers.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet, $mdToast, $mdDialog, About) {

    About.get(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.return.items;
        console.log(data);
    })

}); // End of about controller.
```

`employees` and `boardMembers` works fine with `ng-repeat`, but single record for manager, not

Comment: @ryanyuyu `items` is pretty clear in `About.get()`

Comment: So is the problem that there will sometimes be an array of `managers` or will it always be one object?

Comment: very helpful post [access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @charlietfl So only part of that JSON?  `JSONObj.return.items`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
appControllers.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet, $mdToast,
    $mdDialog, About) {

    About.get(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.return.items;
        $scope.manager = data.return.items.users.manager;       
        console.log(data);
    })
}); // End of about controller.
```

in html:

```
 <p>{{manager.name}}</p>
 <p>{{manager.user}}</p>
```

Comment: This is more easy, working fine, thanks :) P.S.: Edit your code, delete }

Answer (score 0):

If `manager` is always a single object just do:

```
 Manager: {{items.users.manager.name}}
```

Then repeat over the employees array

```
 <div ng-repeat="employee in items.users.employees">
    Employee:  {{employee.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only iterate through a list of `items` using `ng-repeat` if `items` are an array. In your JSON, `items` are an object, so you will not get manager name. Just use `{{items.users.manager.name}}` to get manager name. On the other hand you could use `ng-repeat` to iterate over `items.users.employees`, because it's `employees` property is an array.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="employee in items.users.employees">
    <pre>{{employee.name}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can access it with

```
{{items.users.manager}}
```

Comment: Ahh users is one big object, my bad... Ill edit the answer